# Distance from a right angle to a hypotenuse.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, trigonometry, triangles, pythagorean-triples

Given a right triangle $\,(A,B,C)\,$ with legs $x$ and $y,\,$ there is a point $h$ on the hypotenuse dividing the latter into $h_1$ (from the origin to $h$), and $h_2$ (from $h$ to the end of the hypotenuse away from the origin.

The Distance $\,D\,$ from the right angle to a point $\,h\,$ can be found using the fact that the triangle with vertices (x,h, origin) is similar to $(A,B,C)$ and can be found using the trig formula $\,D=A\sin\theta=A\dfrac{B}{C}=\dfrac{AB}{C}.\quad$ For example, in a $(3,4,5)$ triangle, $D=\dfrac{3\cdot4}{5}=2.4.$

I was wondering if there was a way to find this distance without using trig, using just the Pythagorean Theorem. I have stated with these equations but I don't know where to go from here.

\begin{align*}
H_1^2+D^2&=A^2\\
H_2^2+D^2&=B^2 \\
D^2&=A^2-H_1^2 \\
D^2&=B^2-H_2^2\\
\\
\implies A^2-H_2^1&=B^2-H_2^2\\
\\
\implies A^2-B^2&=H_1^2-H_2^2
\end{align*}

We might have something if we could arrange these to find $H_1+H_2$ but that doesn't seem likely.

Comment: Would Stewart theorem help?  https://brilliant.org/wiki/stewarts-theorem/

Comment: @youthdoo I am looking for the length of a line segment normal to the hypotenuse that ends at the right angle vertex and I would like to find this without trigonometry. I am looking for what amounts to $h$ in the article drawing. I have not been able to figure out how to find that.

Comment: Could you provide a diagram? (Because as much as I've comprehended this problem is just Stewart.)

Comment: Your statement — with the origin and $(x,y)$ — makes no sense to me. Please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You absolutely can do it. Here's one way, working from what you've already done as a starting point but also adding two more facts: $C = H_1 + H_2$ and $C^2 = A^2 + B^2$.

So let's start with the point you go to, with $A^2 - B^2 = H_1^2 - H_2^2$. We can factor the RHS as $H_1^2 - H_2^2 = (H_1 - H_2)(H_1 + H_2) = (H_1 - H_2)C$. Then we can perform some linear elimination to get:

$\begin{eqnarray} & C(H_1 - H_2) & = & A^2 - B^2 \\
& H_1 - H_2 & = & \frac{1}{C}(A^2 - B^2) & (1) \\
& H_1 + H_2 & = & C & (2) \\
(1) + (2): & 2 H_1 & = & C + \frac{1}{C}(A^2 - B^2) \\
&& = & \frac{1}{C}(C^2 + A^2 - B^2) \\
&& = & \frac{1}{C}((A^2 + B^2) + A^2 - B^2) \\
&& = & \frac{2A^2}{C} \\
& \frac{H_1}{A} & = & \frac{A}{C} \end{eqnarray}$

And that gives us the similarity relation that you can then plug into $A^2 + H_1^2 = D^2$ to get the desired final result.

Comment: Beautiful logic. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the problem correctly, you can get this from considering the area of the triangle.  The area of your triangle is $AB/2$.  Considering the hypotenuse as the base, the area is also $CD/2$.  Which gives you $D=AB/C.$

Comment: If I had not already marked the other answer as correct, I would have selected yours because your is more intuitive. Thank you. BTW, not important, but  I'm happy to announce I had a formula published in  [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A058529).